# What's the correct definition of generated ideal in a pseudo-ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, definition

Given a ring (with $1$) $R$, one defines what, say, a left ideal is.
There's also a natural definition of ideal generated by a subset

> **Definition A**: $_R(S):=\bigcap\{I\supseteq S:I\text{ is a left ideal}\}$

Also, one can define (for the purpose of this question) the following left ideal - "$\langle\,\rangle$" stands for the generated additive subgroup:

> **Definition B**: $RS:=\langle rs\,|\,r\in R\wedge s\in S\rangle$

And it holds

> **Characterisation A**: $_R(S)=RS$

Now, these definitions can be extended to pseudo-rings (a.k.a. rngs, a.k.a. rings without unity). Many basic results can be carried over to this case without sensible effort.

One that *cannot* is Charactersation A. Indeed, that is false.
In this notation it would hold instead 
$$_R(S)=\langle x,rs\,|\,r\in R\wedge s\in S\rangle=\langle S\cup RS\rangle$$
and, for instance, $S\not\subseteq RS$ in quite the number of cases.

Nontheless, I thought that the standard definition of ideal generated by $S$ was Definition A, for instance, as it is suggested by [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Ideal_generated_by_a_set).

Recently, I happened to have an argument with a person who claimed that the actual definition in that case was Definition B. We could not discuss the details, though.

I tried doing some research, but what I found did not develop otstandingly this specifical question. Can someone provide me with the correct definition and, in case it is Definition B, some insight on why it is preferred? A reference in a book works as well.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Calling $RS$ the "ideal generated by $S$" is pretty bad, since it's not guaranteed to contain $S$.

Comment: I've deleted "non-empty" (in the introduction of S) since this is not necessary (in fact, such assumptions appear very often but are more confusing than clarifiying).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg you did well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, Definition A is the correct one. ${}_R (S)$ should be the smallest left ideal of $R$ containing $S$. It is additively generated $S$ and "$R \cdot S$". Of course you don't need $-S$ since $r(-s)=-rs$. Even for unital rings, Definition B is not a definition, it should be regarded as a characterization or construction.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29) phrases it as follows:

> If R does not have a unit, then the internal descriptions [of generated ideals] above must be modified slightly. In addition to the finite sums of products of things in X with things in R, we must allow the addition of n-fold sums of the form x+x+...+x, and n-fold sums of the form (−x)+(−x)+...+(−x) for every x in X and every n in the natural numbers. When R has a unit, this extra requirement becomes superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, that was silly of me. I'll edit it, thanks.